# Does const pointer-to-member default to pointing to an int?

Tags: c++, syntax, language-lawyer, variable-declaration, pointer-to-member

While playing with pointers-to-member I encountered a behaviour that seems slightly inconsistent and somewhat counterintuitive to me. Consider the following dummy structure:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    double d;
};
```

and the following `main()`:

```
int main() {
    int foo::* ptr = &foo::x;
    double foo::* ptr2 = &foo::d;
}
```

Here we have nothing unusual - two pointers to `const` members. The code compiles fine.

What caught my attention is that when we add `const`, the situation changes a little bit. Consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    // no int or double after const
    const foo::* ptr = &foo::x;
}
```

The code compiles fine on **GCC 8.2.0**<sup>1</sup>. Notice that I did not specify to what data type the pointer will point.

However, this code:

```
int main() {
    // notice the only change - "d" instead of "x"
    const foo::* ptr = &foo::d;
}
```

fails to compile with the following error:

> error: cannot convert '`double foo::*`' to '`const int foo::*`' in initialization `const foo::* ptr = &foo::d;`

Which is interesting - it suggests that, by default, a `const` pointer-to-member is implicitely declared to point to some `int` member. Is this correct, standard behaviour?

It's worth noting that if we drop the `const`, both of these lines produce errors:

```
int main() {
    foo::* ptr1 = &foo::x;
    foo::* ptr2 = &foo::d;
}
```

in the forms of:

> error: expected unqualified-id before '`*`' token
>
> error: '`ptr1`' | '`ptr2`' was not declared in this scope

So the question is - **does the standard specify that `const` pointer-to-member implicitly points to `int` if we do not specify otherwise, or is it a non-standard behaviour?** (either a GCC extension or GCC bug).

---

<sup>1</sup>EDIT: I am using GCC from MinGW - [this](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html#Download) particular build.

Comment: "*The code compiles fine on GCC 8.2.0*" Eh, no it doesn't.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-fpermissive`? I'd highly recommend not doing that.

Comment: Usually when no type is given, int is assumed. I'm going to guess that's why it works, or rather slides by, for int, but not double.

Comment: @Chipster How often is "usually"?

Comment: @NikosC. it actually [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/OjyDnZ) with -fpermissive and [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/6-QTbo) without it.

Comment: For the record: `const double foo::* ptr = &foo::d;` should compile just fine.

Comment: @Chipster did I suggest otherwise? Did not intend to.

Comment: @curiousguy "usually" means in Visual Studio. It gives a warning when I do things like that saying something to the effect of "int assumed". I'm guessing that's what's going on here, although I don't have an authoritative source to back me up (even though I've looked for one).

Comment: @Fureeish No. I'm just saying if you wanted the code to work as a constant, that should work as intended.

Comment: @Chipster ah yes, I am aware, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is incorrect in ISO C++, but the "implicit int" behaviour is enabled by [`-fms-extensions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554567/) which gcc enables automatically for targeting Microsoft ABI.

You can turn it off with `-fno-ms-extensions`.

---

I checked the source code (gcc-9.1.0/gcc/cp/decl.c),  it turns out that in `ms-extensions` mode the warning for *implicit int* is disabled -- anything that would have generated the message `ISO C++ forbids declaration of %qs with no type` is actually admitted, with `int` being used for the type.

This is probably a bigger hammer than was necessary to solve whatever problem it was trying to solve.  You can also see the discrepancy with `const *x;` or `const f();` for example.

I tried adding `-fno-ms-extensions` to the build for some of my "large" Windows projects that I use mingw-w64 for and got no errors, so perhaps it'd be good practice to give this flag as a matter of habit (or even submit a patch to mingw-w64 to have it off by default...).

Comment: I'll post a followup to my Cygwin bug report. I'm disappointed that, on systems where `-fms-extensions` is enabled by default, `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic` fails to produce required diagnostics. I might submit a bug to gcc.

Comment: Interestingly, `gcc -fms-extensions` warns about implicit `int` in C. Do you happen to know how the option was turned on by default for MinGW and other Windows builds? Is it a configuration option, or did they modify the gcc source? (I'm trying to decide whether this is a gcc bug.)

Comment: @KeithThompson you can check the source code by finding mingw-w64 project on github. AFAIK they don't modify the gcc source at all but they obviously do turn this option on somewhere.   I don't see that a bug report to gcc is warranted as this seems to be intended behaviour , but it might be nice to have finer grained control over the things that `ms-extensions` does (e.g. if they allowed `-Wimplicit-int` to overrule `-fms-extensions`.  One would want to be familiar with the use cases before recommending a change; which I am not. Maybe there is some popular code bases that require this flag.

Comment: They already have a filter to not warn about this if it's identified as a System Header , maybe that doesn't correctly identify windows headers? who knows.

Comment: @KeithThompson On further checking, it turns out the flag control is in the GCC source; it enables it if the Target ABI is a Microsoft one.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is - does the standard specify that const pointer-to-member implicitly points to int if we do not specify otherwise

No. GCC normally will give you the answer in plain English and refuse to compile (or emit a warning if you are using `-fpermissive`):

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'ptr' with no type
```

It is not an extension. It's allowed in `-fpermissive` mode in order to keep very old legacy code compilable.

It seems that GCC as shipped by MinGW-w64 does not catch this error though. I don't know if it's intentional or not.

Comment: The thing is that I compiled **without** `-fpermissive`. It does fail on godbolt, but on my build (I am using MinGW from [here] - STL's build), it still compiles fine, even with no compiler flags. Do you then think it's a bug with MinGW?

Comment: @Fureeish, You should definitely include that in the question. I can reproduce that on my MinGW's GCC 8.1.

Comment: @Fureeish It also happens on a mingw GCC (8.3.0) cross-compiler that I built myself on Linux. Seems to be a general mingw issue (or more correctly, mingw-w64.)

Comment: @Fureeish In comments under the question you said " it actually compiles with `-fpermissive` and does not compile without it." , but now you say it compiles without -fpermissive; which is it?

Comment: I see the same problem with both `g++` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` (both version 7.4.0) on Cygwin. I don't see it with multiple versions of `g++` on Linux. Very odd.

Comment: The `-fpermissive` option doesn't disable the diagnostic; it turns it from a fatal error to a warning. (At least that's what it's supposed to do.) I've submitted a bug report to the Cygwin mailing list. https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2019-06/msg00113.html

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm not using cygwin. I use mingw-w64 under Linux (as a cross compiler) and it has the exact same issue. So it seems completely unrelated to cygwin.

Comment: @NikosC.: Probably -- but I see the problem with MinGW, and under Cygwin, but not on Ubuntu (with the same version of g++, 7.4.0). Maybe the Cygwin folks can track it down.

Comment: @M.M I clearly stated that I compiled on godbolt and locally. On godbolt it fails without -fpermissive, on my compiler it compiles regardlesa of the presence of that flag.

Comment: @KeithThompson It seems this is expected. See M.M's answer.

Comment: @NikosC.: That's ugly -- particularly the fact that `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic` doesn't produce the required diagnostics on systems that turn `-fms-extensions` on by default.